# Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats' has different version for the compile (16.0.1) and runtime (17.0.0) classpath

Tags: java, react-native, google-play-services

Yesterday my app was building correctly and today without changing anything I'm not able to build anymore, I'm getting this error:

> Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats' has >different version for the compile (16.0.1) and runtime (17.0.0) >classpath. You should manually set the same version via >DependencyResolution

I tried to bypass this with "com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true" and clean the project many times, but the error is still here.

My app/build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "io.fabric"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yapero"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 743
        versionName "1.74"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        versionNameSuffix '3'
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/main.kotlin_module'
        exclude 'META-INF/-no-jdk.kotlin_module'
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':@segment_analytics-react-native')
    implementation project(':react-native-webview')
    implementation project(':react-native-version-check')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation(project(':react-native-firebase')) {   
       transitive = false
   }
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {transitive = true}
    //implementation project(':react-native-version-check')
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    implementation project(':react-native-intercom')
    implementation 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:5.+'
    implementation 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-fcm:5.+'
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-appsflyer')
    implementation project(':react-native-text-input-reset')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-fast-image')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0"
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.7'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

Does someone know how to correct or bypass this version check ? Ask me if you need more informations.

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from upgrading to newer gms?

Comment: I just saw your question after posting mine. We seem to have the same problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56650057/what-can-break-an-android-build-without-code-changes

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Upgrading give me new errors and create conflicts with react-native-firebase

Comment: @LaurentS Yes it's the same, I also have the error with dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base'

Comment: Just found this as a likely culprit: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[This comment on github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25293#issuecomment-503045776) provides the answer to your question (and mine):

A dependency (`react-native-device-info` in this case) was using the latest version of one of its dependencies instead of a fixed/pinned version. When a new version of google services was [released yesterday](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019), it caused the build to pull in the new version for `device-info`, thereby causing the conflict with other dependencies that correctly pin the version they need.

The solution is to do what is explained in the linked post in your `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
implementation(project(":react-native-device-info"),  {
  exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
})
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0"
```

and possibly replace `react-native-device-info` with any other dependency that may have the same problem (they would include a line like `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+"` which depends on whatever is the latest version of google gcm).

Comment: This solution helped me for running the app in debug mode but when I try to build an APK using ´gradlew assembleRelease´ I still get errors.

Comment: @jmn try app:assembleRelease

Answer (score 2):

Add in the file: android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
    ...
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    }
```