# Problem with merge manifest in React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest, release, fastlane

I'am building my with fastlane `bundle exec fastlane dev`.
I got this error after I have linked image assets by `react-native link`.

Error:

```
> Task :app:processReleaseManifest FAILED
/Users/sko/bmind/projects/BatteryGuru/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
    Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-38:19 to override.
```

My `app/build.gradle` dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-config')
    implementation project(':react-native-reanimated')
    implementation project(':react-native-sentry')
    implementation project(':easy-bluetooth-classic')
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-i18n')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

Packages:

`"react-native": "0.59.3",
"react": "16.8.3",`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is probably due to react-native-device-info (and possibly another dependency) using the newest Google Play Services GCM which relies on AndroidX. 
You can update to the newest version ( `yarn upgrade react-native-device-info@2.1.2` ), and check these answers if it does not fix your issue :

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648263/android-dependency-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-stats-has-different-ve)

[Github: Android : Unable to build app](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25293#issuecomment-503045776)