# Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base' has different version for the compile (16.0.1) and runtime (17.0.0) classpath

Tags: react-native

I am working on react native. while I am running the application i am getting below error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

  > Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base' has different v
  >   ersion for the compile (16.0.1) and runtime (17.0.0) classpath. You should manua
  >   lly set the same version via DependencyResolution
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

This is My Code

In android/build.grdle

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {

    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 22
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google() // now here
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
         maven {
           url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' 
         classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.29.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
                // Add jitpack repository (added by react-native-spinkit)
        google()
                maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }

    }
}

subprojects {

    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
              && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "28.0.0"
            }
                // Remove this if you get error in maps
            else if(details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "16.0.0"
            }
        }
    }

    afterEvaluate { 
        project -> if (project.hasProperty("android")) { 
            android { 
                compileSdkVersion 28 
                buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
            } 
        } 
    } 
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}



In android/app/build.gradle

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    signingConfigs {
        /* Configure the release Key's here before play store build*/
        config {
            keyAlias 'key0'
            keyPassword 'navman'
            storeFile file('../keystores/PurpleSSCert')
            storePassword 'navman'
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.teletracnavman.site360"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
/* YYMMDDHHMM UTC of build. Typically use 00 minutes for release build */       
        versionCode 1906141700
/* Major.Minor.YYMM.DDHH */     
        versionName '1.3.1906.1417'
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
/* No need to include "x86" in default Android app */
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-geocoder')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-i18n')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
    implementation project(':react-native-orientation-locker')
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-orientation')
    implementation project(':react-native-photo-view')
    implementation project(':react-native-preference')
    implementation(project(':react-native-camera')) {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
    }
    implementation project(':react-native-fs')
    implementation project(':rn-fetch-blob')
    implementation project(':realm')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.0'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: This is my codeIn android/buid.gradle

Comment: try changing the version of com-google-android-gmsplay-services-base to 17.0.0

Comment: Hi @santosh, your question seems to be the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648263/android-dependency-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-stats-has-different-ve

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/issues/37) adding the following line at the bottom of your app's build.gradle can solve your problem.

```
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Comment: I tried with same solution still i am getting same issue

Comment: have you applied the plugin **com.google.gms.google-services** which is mentioned in that link?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue yesterday. In my case, updating device info library to the latest version fixed this issue.

```
npm install --save react-native-device-info@2.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is related migration to `Androidx`, google play service updated to `androidX`

If you are using `real-native-info`, please upgrade. It will solve your problem with **2.1.2**

```
yarn upgrade react-native-device-info@2.1.2
cd android && gradlew clean
react-native run-android
```

See [here apply link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25294#issuecomment-503042684)

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56650057/11212074) to this question

> Apply Note: Upgrading `com.google.android.gms` to 17.0.0 will cause many
>   problems.

This solution will help you.